# Web Application Framework Compatibility with WP Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

What Web Application frameworks are compatible with WordPress? For example; can I use Angular.JS or Zend in my WordPress plugin or will I run into compatibility issues or roadblocks that wont allow me to fully use all features of Angular or Zend?

I am developing a plugin that is similar Adobe Photoshop except inside WordPress. You will be able to drag, resize, rotate, edit images, text and buttons. Its very UI intensive and complex and thus standard PHP, JQuery and WP AJAX Postback library wont cut it. The code will be an absolute mess. I need to be able to bind front end UI elements to backend models.

Thus I need to use a Web Application Framework. Whats has the industry used in the past for WP Plugins? For example; maybe well known plugins like Revolution Slider or Master Slider use a specific JS or PHP framework?

Comment: Don't know about php frameworks but I have successfully used WordPress with AngularJS and EmberJS. JS framework has nothing to do with what you use on your backend except you will need to provide a rest interface for them. I used [WP REST API](http://wp-api.org/) without any problem.

Comment: @Sisir thanks for your comment. Which do you recommend Angular or Ember? Is there one that you found better suited?

Comment: Not really! You can use one over another. Both are different so stick with one once you start to learn it. Personally I liked ember better but I have to warn you both Ember and Angular has steep learning curve. So, if you are learning you shouldn't be using it on a project that has strict timeline. Also community support is not as wide as WP.